# Maven successfully add dependency but found nothing in lib

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

Here is my pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>parent-web</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>web-amazon-auth</artifactId>
    <description>
        Amazon Auth
    </description>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>web-common</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--mybatis-plus-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--failed dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.baomidou</groupId>
            <artifactId>dynamic-datasource-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.1024</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>sts</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.81</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>auth</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.81</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!--quick boot-->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <!--fork: required to enable devtool-->
                    <fork>true</fork>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

That was quite strange, All the dependencies added below tag `<!--failed dependencies-->` are successfully added to maven, but I cannot use them in my code.

By searching them in lib, there is nothing until I force add them manually from module setting, this situation will not happen in any of other modules. I have tried to clean or invalid cache and restart, also I have tried to relink the child pom to the parent, so far , only force add manually worked. I don't know how to fix this...

All the required jars are normal in my maven repository, and they all run well in my other projects with the same `pom.xml`. I'm stuck here for a long time why the jars will not added into lib in this module.

Comment: What do you mean by `lib`? What actual error do you get, and what command are you running when you get it?

Comment: @tgdavies External Libraries in IDEA, so far I have solved the problem by unlink the module from parent pom, and added it to the parent again, invalid cache and restart IDEA, all the dependencies are normal after that... I wonder if there are some hidding configurations which leads to this problem, and by doing re-adding pom, the broken configurations are corrected by IDEA automatically.